# How to copy timecode value from a video to clipboard on a mac

Tags: premiere, mac, quicktime, timecode

Is there any app that can copy timecode values to clipboard?

I'm playing a video.  I want to stop the video, press a keyboard shortcut, then go to a google doc and paste the timecode value (not a video frame).

I'm using a Mac.  Tried googling for solutions in Quicktime Player, Adobe Premiere, Final Cut, but can't find anything.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in Apple's Motion (but not FCPX for some reason). To do so, create a new project and import your footage. You'll want the project's frame rate and starting timecode to match the footage's. Next, set the timeline to display timecode by clicking on the downward facing arrow next to the timecode:

[image: Timecode controls]

Select the Timecode option:

[image: Show Timecode]

Then double-click to select the timecode:

[image: Select It]

Now you can copy/paste it or type in a new value to jump there.

Comment: Hi.  My question is whether there's a single keyboard shortcut in any of these apps which can grab the timecode value without having to go through the extra steps you've outlined. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of any. To do this in Motion, once you do the initial setup, it's just a double-click and Cmd-C to copy. Not too onerous, but I don't know of any that are less than that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it came up in a google search I was doing.  So, in case this helps, I've been using a program called TCode4 that does exactly what you're asking for:  http://timecodesoftware.com/tcode

A couple caveats: I think the video needs to have a separate timecode track, not just burned-in timecode.  Also, when I open it recently, I get a message saying that it needs to be updated.  I'm assuming it's a 32-bit app that needs to be updated to 64-bit for Catalina or something like that, and I'm not sure that it will be.  That is, I'm not sure the program's still in active development.